# how to run an ocx from a service by specifying the user session

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I would like to create run a delphi service that create a Tform with a wordOcx that write a document, and thus far, I have no problems, but I would like that service to run the (word.exe) process in a specific user session.

thanks corchi

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for the service to directly specify which user session an out-of-process COM object runs under.  You would have to create a separate .exe file for the service to run, and have that .exe access WordOcx as needed, instead of accessing it inside the service directly.  The service can then use `CreateProcessAsUser()` to run the .exe in a specific user session.

Comment: ok thanks, do you know  the sites where I can find the examples how to use CreateProcessAsUser?